# javascript(ajax) and php working together?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem that my Js file is not recognizing a php variable built by ajax.
Here is an example:

index.php:

```
<script src="js.js">
</script>
<?
include('build.php');
<div id="brand">
<?
   echo $brandinput;
?>
</div>
//....more code
?>
```

build.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
       crossOrigin: true,
       dataType: "jsonp",
       type: "GET",
       url: "getBrand.php",
       data: info,
       success: function(data){
             $("#result").html(data); 
       }

     });
     </script>
     <?php $brandinput='<div id="result"></div>'; 
      ?>
```

js.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//dosomething with div's in index.php
}
```

So, I'll try to explain this in the easiest way. My index.php includes a build.php which as you can see calls ajax to retrieve data from another server. This data is located in a php variable (`$brandinput`) which will contain many `<div>,<input>,... etc.`  Then index.php echo $brandinput, showing all the content of the variable. But I have a js.js which change appearances in div's, input's, etc.. and is this js which is not recognizing the content of the variable $brandinput.

I'd like to know if you have more ideas or what am I doing wrong...
All the code is working well, I tested many times **(except for what I said before)**
The ajax call work well and Index.php displays `$braninput` correctly.

p.s. `$brandinput` is something like this:

```
<div id='BlackBerry'><img src='..\/images\/supporteddevices\/blackberry-logo.jpg' alt='blackberry-logo' width='75'><br><input class='adjustRadio' type='radio'
```

and yeah it works well too.

Comment: 1. Why are you using JSONP for same domain request? 2. `$ brandinput` is what you set it to be on build.php 3. There is no tag called textfield in HTML.  You probably meant textarea

Comment: 1. I retrieve data from another server, so is not same domain.2. yes it is. 3. yeah sorry I changed that in the last minute, edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is how it supposed to be working, what you need to do is to wait for the ajax request to finish first before executing the functions in `js.js`

try this way

```
// in build.php
$(document).ready(function () {
    var promise = $.ajax({
        crossOrigin: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "GET",
        url: "getBrand.php",
        data: info,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);

            //dosomething with div's in index.php
        }
    });
});
```

or (assuming js.js is loaded *after* the script within build.php, or js.js has to be loaded after it)

```
// in build.php
$(document).ready(function () {
    var promise = $.ajax({
        crossOrigin: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "GET",
        url: "getBrand.php",
        data: info,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
});

// in js.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    promise.then(function (data) {
        //dosomething with div's in index.php
    });
});
```

**P.S**

`$brandinput` just hold the string whatever assigned to, and will never be changed with ajax request, where ajax success handler just manipulate the rendered DOM directly in the client side.

Comment: Just did that but it didn't work. I'm now thinking that my js.js is not reading the content of `$brandInput`. But my html did read it cause it shows me exactly what I want on the screen when I use `echo $brandInput`. I'll keep looking for some answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving your `<script>` tag to after your php codes like this:

```
<? include('build.php'); ?>
<div id="brand">
    <? echo $brandinput; ?>
</div>
<script src="js.js"></script>

//....more code
```

On a slightly different note, you should consider avoid embedding/intermixing PHP codes with HTML and Javascript. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/1144203) for better ways way "passing data from PHP to Javascript".